# How to access names by which data members are declared in c++ and output those names to console

Tags: c++, debugging, datamember

Code:

```
class A
{
    private:
        int abc;
        string xyz;
}
```

In the above code, how can I access the names by which data members are declared (`abc`, `xyz`) and  print them to console?

Comment: Do you wants: `A a;` `cout << a.abc;` **?**

Comment: He's probably looking for reflection, to which I say: wait for C++14/17 !

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of is using a macro:

```
#define PRINT_VAR(x) std::cout << #x << '\n';
```

C++ doesn't have the reflection capabilities of other languages.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean accessing the names of members, as strings, without knowing those names beforehand, that's not possible - C++ doesn't support reflection.